# send link in email message using codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, email, hyperlink

I am trying to send a email to newly registered user, and in that email I am sending a link with verification code, if user clicks this link then only his account will be activated.

I managed to send email, but the link is just a text, it is not acting as hyperlink, 
here is my code

```
$verification_code = "dkeoKUd";

$this->email->from('xyz@xyz.com', 'xyz');
$this->email->to($user_email);
$this->email->subject('Email Test');

$link = 'Click on this link - <a http://localhost/Registration_Demo/update_verification_status/update_code='.$verification_code.'>http://localhost/Registration_Demo/update_verification_status/update_code='.$verification_code.'</a>';

$this->email->message($link);
$this->email->send();
```

And in the constructor of this controller I wrote

```
$this->load->library('email');
$this->email->set_mailtype("html");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the link is missing an href :

```
Registration_Demo/update_verification_status/update_code='.$verification_code.'>http://localhost/Registration_Demo/update_verification_status/update_code='.$verification_code.'</a>'
```

As a result, the a tag will not work